# Rock, Paper, Scissors. Code won't read user input that's lowercase

Tags: python

I made a rock paper scissors game (code below). Is there a simpler way of making the code able to read both uppercase and lowercase inputs? So far, it only reads uppercase (i.e. Rock, Paper, Scissors). If the input is lowercase (i.e. rock, paper, scissors), the game won't tell you if you've won or not.

```
import random
import time

options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

yourMove = input("Rock, paper, or scissors? \n ---------- \n")
computerChoice = (random.choice(options))

print("Rock...")
time.sleep(1)
print("Paper...")
time.sleep(1)
print("Scissors...")
time.sleep(1)
print("Shoot! \n")
time.sleep(1)

print("You chose " + yourMove)
print("The computer chose " + computerChoice + "\n")

if yourMove == "Rock" and computerChoice == "Paper":
    print("You lose!")
elif yourMove == "Paper" and computerChoice == "Rock":
    print("You win!")

if yourMove == "Scissors" and computerChoice == "Rock":
    print("You lose!")
elif yourMove == "Rock" and computerChoice == "Scissors":
    print("You win!")

if yourMove == "Paper" and computerChoice == "Scissors":
    print("You lose!")
elif yourMove == "Scissors" and computerChoice == "Paper":
    print("You win!")

if yourMove == computerChoice:
    print("It's a draw!")
```

Comment: What have you looked at to try to solve your problem? Do you know about all the methods available for strings?

Comment: well yeah, `"rock"!="Rock"`. For case-insensitive comparison, you should convert your input to upper/lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that if you are going to work with strings in a list, leave everything in lowercase.

When capturing the value desired by the user, you could use:

```
value = input("[Text] ").lower().strip()
```

Python is a case sensitive language, so

```
"Paper" != "paper" or " paper " != "  paper"
```

Answer (score 0):

python has many methods to work with strings.
your program can use many of them and work.
here are some solutions.

1- use `lower()` to make user input all lowercase and your options should be lower cased too.

```py
options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
yourMove = input("Rock, paper, or scissors? \n ---------- \n").lower()
```

2- use `upper()` to make user input all uppercase and your options should be upper case.

```py
options = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"]
yourMove = input("Rock, paper, or scissors? \n ---------- \n").upper()
```

3- or you can keep your current options and just use `capitalize()` to make the first letter uppercase.

```py
options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
yourMove = input("Rock, paper, or scissors? \n ---------- \n").capitalize()
```